# Configure Cntlm to use no proxy if none are available in 2021

Tags: cntlm

Found an old question (8 years ago) about this re: cntlm - and the answer was it's "on the roadmap" - so wondering if anyone has driven there yet?

The problem is simple - on a corporate machine.  When I connect to the vpn - I have to use the corporate proxy.  When I am *not* connected to the vpn - I have to *not* use it.  I want to be able to setup everything to talk to proxy in the way that it all works, all the time - and I do not want to have to do an action or anything every time I connect or disconnect from the vpn.

so - really, I want to setup cntlm to point to Proxy X - but have it go directly if X isn't available.  I know I can setup squid and provide it as a second proxy, but I end up having a lot of extra stuff running on my machine.

Comment: I believe, no one can these days starts something with the short-term cntlm if it's so aged. How's about to describe your business related issue to start over and link your question as reference? I am unsure if you can use bounty your question, but it will and might be raising the attention to it